# Can I create a false ceiling using XPS board instead of gypsum board?

Tags: insulation

I want to install a false ceiling on the top floor in the classrooms of a school.

I have installed a grid structure and now, instead of using gypsum boards, I want to use XPS insulation boards of 1" and more.

My question is: how can we putty-paint those boards so they give an aesthetic look to the classroom?

Comment: As Steven mentions, this is not to code in most places.

Answer (score 5):

XPS must be covered with drywall or another fire resistant material.  XPS, when exposed to heat will put off toxic fumes and will melt.  The last thing you want in a class room is molten foam melting onto students in the event of a fire.

Stick with proper ceiling tiles, drywall or another **suitable** material.  What you are proposing would be against most building codes that I know of, at least in North America.

Comment: Definite need for the drywall cover, you don't want a "Great White" Station Nightclub Disaster. Especially in a school. Because foam caught fire.